# MATE dictionary not listed on accessories menu

Tags: mate

I'm running MATE on Ubuntu 18.04 and I do not have the Dictionary listed in my Applications > Accessories menu. I do however have Artha, which is useful but not what I want.

When entering `mate-dictionary` into the command line the following appears:

```
Gtk-Message: 07:21:55.447: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"
```

Then the dictionary opens and functions as expected.

I would like to have the dictionary available from the GUI rather than having to access the terminal each time.

Any help would be appreciated.
Hal.

Comment: what commands did you run to have MATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATE Dictionary is located in Office category. Please check it out:

> [image: MATE Dictionary]

The warning message may be removed by

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99mate-environment
```

(this file is a leftover from 16.04 LTS and should be removed on 18.04 LTS - [see bug](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-settings/issues/3))

Comment: That was an excellent, succinct answer, much appreciated. Hal.